# Tomcat isn't working

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, server, deploying

I'm trying to run Tomcat 7.0.75 integrated in my Intellij with simple Helloworld web-app on java servlet. And i get this output:

```
D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin\catalina.bat run
Cannot find "В«D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\binВ»\bin\setclasspath.bat"
Disconnected from server
This file is needed to run this program
```

I installed TomCat, and preparing web-app using instructions from internet. I set CATALINA_BASE and CATALINA_HOME variables, of course.
I can't find same strange output string

```
Cannot find "В«D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\binВ»\bin\setclasspath.bat"
```

Maybe this incorrect path is the cause, but i have no idea what to do. That's my first experience with servers in java.

Comment: I think incorrect path is the actual issue `"В«D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\binВ»\bin\setclasspath.bat"` doesn't seem to right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to install tomcat 8 or 9 version.

Id Idea->Run->Edit configurations->click on "plus"->Tomcat Server->Local

**Server tab**: 
Application Server - choose your tomcat

open browser - http://localhost:8080/*your war package name*/

http port: 8080

where *your war package name* - is root of your app - in pom.xml see section: build -> finalName

**Deployment tab**:
add *your war package name*:war exploded
with application context /*your war package name*